# ¿Qué puedo hacer con el desbordamiento de memoria en la libreria phpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, out-of-memory-error

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function imprimir($array) {
ini_set('memory_limit', '3600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);



$variable = 1;
if ($variable > 0) {

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('Este archivo solo se puede ver desde un navegador web');

    /** Se agrega la libreria PHPExcel */
    require_once 'resource/assets/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Movimiento_por_comprobante.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings =  array('memoryCacheSize' => '3600MB', 'cacheTime' => '3000');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);



        // Se crea el objeto PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // Se asignan las propiedades del libro
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Codedrinks") //Autor
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Codedrinks") //Ultimo usuario que lo modificó
    ->setTitle("Movimiento por comprobante")
    ->setSubject("Movimiento por comprobante")
    ->setDescription("Movimiento por comprobante")
    ->setKeywords("comprobante")
    ->setCategory("Reporte excel");

    $tituloReporte = "MOVIMIENTO POR COMPROBANTE";
    $titulosColumnas = array('Consecutivo', 'Fecha', 'Centro de costo', 'Tipo Documento', 'Tipo Comprobante', 'Numero Documento', 'Cuenta', 'Nombre', 'Nit', 'Nombre', 'Descripcion', 'Debitos', 'Creditos');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->mergeCells('A1:H1');

        // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', $tituloReporte)
    ->setCellValue('A3', $titulosColumnas[0])
    ->setCellValue('B3', $titulosColumnas[1])
    ->setCellValue('C3', $titulosColumnas[2])
    ->setCellValue('D3', $titulosColumnas[3])
    ->setCellValue('E3', $titulosColumnas[4])
    ->setCellValue('F3', $titulosColumnas[5])
    ->setCellValue('G3', $titulosColumnas[6])
    ->setCellValue('H3', $titulosColumnas[7])
    ->setCellValue('I3', $titulosColumnas[8])
    ->setCellValue('J3', $titulosColumnas[9])
    ->setCellValue('K3', $titulosColumnas[10])
    ->setCellValue('L3', $titulosColumnas[11])
    ->setCellValue('M3', $titulosColumnas[12]);

        //Se agregan los datos de todas las columnas
    $i = 4;

    $a = 1;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A' . $i, $value['mc_consec'])
        ->setCellValue('B' . $i, $value['mc_fecdoc'])
        ->setCellValue('C' . $i, $value['mc_cencos'])
        ->setCellValue('D' . $i, $value['mc_tipdoc'])
        ->setCellValue('E' . $i, $value['mc_tipcom'])
        ->setCellValue('F' . $i, $value['mc_numdoc']);

        $i++;
        foreach ($value['detalle'] as $llave2 => $valor) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('C' . $i, $valor['tr_cencos'])
            ->setCellValue('G' . $i, $valor['tr_cuenta'])
            ->setCellValue('H' . $i, $valor['pc_nomcue'])
            ->setCellValue('I' . $i, $valor['tr_nit'])
            ->setCellValue('J' . $i, $valor['nt_nombre'])
            ->setCellValue('K' . $i, $valor['tr_descri'])
            ->setCellValue('L' . $i, $valor['debito'])
            ->setCellValue('M' . $i, $valor['credito']);

            $i++;


        }
        if (isset($value['debitos'])) {
            $debitos = $value['debitos'];
        } else {

            $debitos = 0;
        }
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('B' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('C' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('D' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('E' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('F' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('G' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('H' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('I' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('J' . $i, "----")
        ->setCellValue('K' . $i, "Total")
        ->setCellValue('L' . $i, $debitos)
        ->setCellValue('M' . $i, $value['creditos']);
        $i++;
    }


    for ($i = 'A'; $i <= 'M'; $i++) {//redimensionando las columnas
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
    }


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Movimiento');






    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');


    return $objWriter;
} else {
    print_r('No hay resultados para mostrar');
}
}




 public function consultar2($array) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '3600M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);        
    $objWriter = $this->imprimir($array);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    unset($objWriter);
    exit();        

}
```

Pasa lo siguiente: Al momento de ejecutar consultas SQL que tengan menos de 200.000 registros no hay problema con el excel, el sistema es capaz de crearlo y guardarlo. Pero cuando la consulta sql supera este número hay un desbordamiento de memoria en la librería.
Cualquier consejo es bienvenido.
Gracias.

Comment: no es la libreria excel es la cantidad de registros que estas consultando, tienes dos opciones obligar al usuario que utilice un filtro para disminuir la cantidad de regitros o consultas cada xx registros guardas el archivo de manera local hasta que finalice y luego lo envias

Comment: ¿Comprar más RAM? 200.000 registros no son poca cosa, y los formatos MS Office suelen ser complicados para generar...

Comment: gracias, intentare las soluciones! y comentare al respecto.

Comment: Quisiera comentar al respecto: PHPExcel está descontinuado, dándole paso a Phpspreadsheet, aunque este último también es un dragón de memoria, alrededor de 1.6Kb por celda, así que calcula tu matriz representada. Te recomiendo pruebes open spout, a mi me ha servido de maravillas en cuanto a consumo de memoria., Aunque mirando la cantidad de registros que deseas reflejar en el Excel, primero debes optimizar tu query empezando por hacer un procesamiento por lotes, y como otros te sugirieron, en última instancia generar un CSV, mucho más liviano.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es básicamente un comentario más que una respuesta, pero necesito el espacio extra.

Una vez dicho lo de que lo más sencillo es simplemente aumentar la RAM (no es que haya un fallo de programación, es que estás haciendo una consulta y un Excel muy grandes), si no hay más remedia quedan un par de opciones a explorar:

- Generar un CSV y que el usuario lo importe, o hacer la conversión a Excel una vez que la conexión a BD ha sido cerrada.
- Generar el Excel en varios ficheros separados y buscar un programa o una función que los concatene (de nuevo, una vez que la conexión haya quedado liberada).
- Como el `xlsx` es al fin y al cabo XML, generar tú ese XML. La ventaja es que generas el fichero secuencialmente (fila a fila); como sabes que no vas a "volver para atras" (cambiar el valor de A40 cuando estás procesando B20359) no tienes en memoria más que una pequeña parte del fichero (la ya procesada la envías a un fichero o al navegador).

*Caveat Emptor* como he avisado antes, esto es un comentario. No garantizo que alguna de las opciones te solucione el problema, pero son opciones que yo exploraría si estuviera en esa situación. Vuelvo a insistir que lo mejor es que le digas a tu jefe "cambiar la solución llevará X días que son Z € (o lo que sea), y no está garantizado que funcione... ¿seguro que no es más barato poner más RAM?".

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intentare y comentare al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías buscar alguna forma de paginar. Esto es:

1) En vez de recorrer todos los resultados de búsqueda en el for, los recorrés con un while, iterando por cada 10.000 (por ejemplo).

2) en cada iteración, guardás las filas en un archivo excel.
Así, si tenés (por ejemplo) 400.000 resultados, tendrías 40 archivos excel. Supongamos:

> excel1.xls
>
> excel2.xls ...
>
> excel40.xls

3) cuando terminen las 10.000 iteraciones, guardás el archivo en disco y cerrás el archivo.

4) Cuando hayan terminado todas las iteraciones, se me ocurre que podés abrir cada archivo generado y ir mergeandolos en uno solo, valiéndote, por ejemplo, de un método como el siguiente:

```
class XlsHelper {
    public static function mergeXls($fromFileName,&$target) {
        $from = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fromFileName);

        foreach($from->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
            $target->addExternalSheet($sheet)
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, deberías iterar por cada excel que tengas, y hacer algo así:

```
$target = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("excel1.xls");
for($i=2;$i<=$cantidadDeArchivos;$i++) {
    XlsHelper::mergeXls("excel2.xls",$target);
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($target, "Excel1");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel1.xls");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

No estoy seguro de que funcione bien (no sé bien como administra la memoria el phpexcel o php en sí), pero se me ocurre como una alternativa.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo de configuración de php (`php.ini`), revisa los siguientes parámetros:

La cantidad de memoria RAM que se puede usar, por default viene en 128MB. Debes aumentarlo para poder cargar archivos grandes en memoria.

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Mira el tamaño del archivo y de acuerdo a ello modifica este par de parámetros que indican qué tanto puedes subir al servidor:

```
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```